# How to convert the SQL query to mongodb query

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB Atlas in my project. I tried to build the query but i got some issues.

[image]

```sql
select top 20 * 
from users 
where _id not in (select following=0
                     from users 
                     where _id = myuserid)
```

I tried to convert the query but I can't.

```
"{\"collection\":\"users\",\"stages\":[{\"$match\":{\"$and\":[{\"status\":\"active\"},{\"_id\":{\"$ne\":{\"$oid\":[{\"$match\":[{\"_id\":{\"$oid\":\"%%args.user\"}},{\"following\":{\"$size\":0}}]},{\"$project\":{\"_id\":1}}]}}}]}}]}"
```

Can you please help me out with the solution?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is good to put an example of your data to be more clear

Comment: @Ashkan i have modified the query

Comment: something wrong, _id is unique, then, if you search for documents whose following array size is 0 and _id === mysuerid. it will return you one record. something wrong In your question or query.

Comment: use https://mongoplayground.net/ to make an example and try to explain better.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following way:

```js
db.collection.find({
  userid: {
    $ne: myuserid
  }
}).limit(20)
```

Comment: I have add the users collection image and modified the query. can you please look into the query. the above query is not working

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)